# Pass a schema name and table name dynamically in FROM in a select query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

- Pass a schema name and table name dynamically in FROM in a select query in postgres.
- I need to call a table dynamically in a from (in the select clause)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xx.fn_build_test_(
    IN p_var_archive_schema character varying,
    IN p_var_archive_table character varying)

 RETURNS record AS
 $BODY$
   declare

l_var_archive_schema  VARCHAR;
l_var_archive_table VARCHAR; 
l_var_test VARCHAR[];

BEGIN

l_var_archive_schema  := p_var_archive_schema;
l_var_archive_table   := p_var_archive_table;

SELECT  array
( SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name,'YYYYMMDD')
 FROM "test_table"
 WHERE col1 = 1)
 INTO l_var_test;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE SECURITY INVOKER;
```

I need values for:

l_var_archive_schema  VARCHAR;
  l_var_archive_table VARCHAR;

in place of the test table

Answer (score 1):

You do not need those local variables for schema and table.
Use format option to construct the queries and `EXECUTE` to run it dynamically

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xx.fn_build_test_(
 IN p_var_archive_schema character varying,
 IN  p_var_archive_table character varying )
 RETURNS record AS
 $BODY$
 DECLARE
  l_var_test VARCHAR[];

 BEGIN

 SELECT  array
  ( SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name,'YYYYMMDD')
    FROM "test_table"
   WHERE col1 = 1
   ) INTO l_var_test;

   EXECUTE format (
     'select col_name FROM %I.%I',
         p_var_archive_schema,p_var_archive_table) 
      --INTO rec_variable;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE SECURITY INVOKER;
```

If you want to return the result of a dynamic query you may use

`RETURNS TABLE` option and then do `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` to return results from the query.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). For example change the SQL in the function as following. The function needs further correction as by definition it is supposed to return a record but currently not returning any value.

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT  array
( SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name,''YYYYMMDD'')
  FROM '||l_var_archive_schema||'.'||l_var_archive_table||' WHERE col1 = 1)'
  INTO l_var_test;
```

Comment: That is not safe from SQL injection.