# How do I replace an argument in queries inside a plpsql function?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a function named public.stepone(...) which will take some argument and replace it with the passed value in all queries inside the function as shown below. here public is the schemaname. The argument passed in also the schemaname which should be replaced in all the queries.

for example if I call the function from command line as :
SELECT public.stepone(26) where 26 is another schemaname, all the queries should replace 26 in the place of schemaname.

for e.g the first query would then be
  UPDATE 26.tablename SET col = someValue;

**What I have Tried**

DECLARE
schemaname integer:=schemaname

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.stepone(schemaname IN integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN

       UPDATE schemaname.tablename SET col= someValue;


    END;
    $BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.stepone(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: You need to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: what changes would I have to make in the function code for that?

Comment: Read the documentation that my link points to and you will know.

Comment: Resolved this by dynamic sql. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331238/pass-a-schema-name-and-table-name-dynamically-in-from-in-a-select-query-in-postg